# Liferay 7 Json WS External JAR

Tags: json, liferay, osgi

I have a osgi module (service-builder) to create a WS Json. 
My Bnd.Bnd File is Like:

```
Bundle-Name: Dummy-service
Bundle-SymbolicName: Dummy.service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath:\
.,\
lib/joda-time.jar
-includeresource:\
lib/joda-time.jar=lib/joda-time-2.8.1.jar
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0
Liferay-Service: true
```

My build.gradle :

```
dependencies 
{
  compile group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
  compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: 
    "3.0.0"
  compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", 
  version: "2.0.0"
  compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", 
  version: "2.6.0"
  compile group: "com.liferay", name: liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.api", 
    version: "3.5.4"
  compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.api", version: 
    "2.6.1"
  compile project(":modules: DummyApi: DummyApi-api")
  compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.8.1'
}

buildService {
 apiDir = "../Dummy-api/src/main/java"
}

group = "DummyEventApi"
```

When i generate de jar of the service and explode it, i have correctly the jar in the lib folder, but when i deploy the service i got the following error:

```
 .service [515]_ Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.joda.convert_
```

I read (and based the code) in David article: 
https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies

I choosed the option 4, but when i deploy the service allways got the error, and if i remove the code from joda-time the service starts correctly.

Can somewone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this thread of liferay community:

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/89485697